# Jmeter CSV file for Json

Tags: json, csv, request, jmeter

im new to jmeter.
I'm in need to test the performance of some json requests which normally do some insertion or update in db .

I need to  change some record id dynamically . For example

```
{"columnName":"company","newValue":"cts","oldValue":"","timeStamp":"11-05-2012 14:54:24","version":"1"}],"instruction":"contact_list","**recordId**":"8294547"}]}
```

i want record id should be dynamically get from csv file. so i did like

```
 "recordid":"$recordid"}
```

But after HIT TO THE SERVER I found in the request THAT the one more time request id was printing after the json loop ends like

```
{"columnName":"company","newValue":"cts","oldValue":"","timeStamp":"11-05-2012 14:54:24","version":"1"}],"instruction":"contact_list","recordId":"**8294547**"}]}
```

**8294547**

which returns to malformed json request.

can u please tell the way to avoid extra appending recordid after the json loop .

above json is not the actual one just i copied the part i need .

Answer (score 5):

You're missing curly braces. The format for inserting a variable in JMeter is ${myVar}, not $myVar.